# Vim: change mouse click behavior

Tags: vim, vi

I am playing with my vimrc settings, and enabled the mouse support.

```
set mouse=a
```

Now, I miss the copy and paste option with mouse. Normally, if the mouse is not enabled, I could copy text with left click + drag, and paste by right click (in Insert mode). So,

How to get the copy, paste with mouse enabled (with mouse click, not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> etc). The only option I need with mouse enabled is to click anywhere in the file and the cursor points to that location. This helps faster navigation.

I use putty (x-term) to connect to my debian server.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Easiest solution is just to hold shift down when you select text, to get the old behavior for mouse-copy. Paste with shift-mouseclick will usually work too.

Comment: thanks..that is a reasonable way, and works too.. let me wait for any other option, else accept this.. thanks

Comment: Holy kitten mittens. Seven years I've used vim, and I always just dealt with it. Always learning something new with vim :)

Answer (score 6):

jkerian's solution is generally what I do, but if you ever find yourself wanting to copy and paste a lot, and getting tired of holding down shift, you can do something like this:

```
" toggle between terminal and vim mouse
map <silent><F12> :let &mouse=(&mouse == "a"?"":"a")<CR>:call ShowMouseMode()<CR>
imap <silent><F12> :let &mouse=(&mouse == "a"?"":"a")<CR>:call ShowMouseMode()<CR>
function ShowMouseMode()
    if (&mouse == 'a')
        echo "mouse-vim"
    else
        echo "mouse-xterm"
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

On OSX in a Terminal window you need to hold down the <kbd>fn</kbd> key when you want to select some text with the mouse in vim that you want to copy. You can tell it's selected as it is highlighted in a different colour (for the 'Homebrew' profile it's blue) as opposed to vim's default highlight colour (e.g. green). Then you can copy the selected text as usual using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

And to add if you want to do this in iTerm2 you need to hold down the <kbd>⌥</kbd> (Alt/Option) and mouse to select text for copying - see the [iTerm2 FAQ](https://iterm2.com/faq.html) for more selection region options.

Comment: Annoyingly if you have line numbers turned on, this copies the line numbers too

Answer (score 1):

Hold the shift button and select the text to copy.
Then either click middle mouse button or right click to paste in console. To paste in vim, shift+insert in insert mode.